# 文章が書かれている行数だけを調べるコマンドが知りたい

Tags: linux, ubuntu

テキストファイルに書かれている文章だけの行数を調べるコマンドが知りたいです。

例えば…

（一行目）文章が書かれている行数だけを調べるコマンドが知りたい
（二行目）文章が書かれている行数だけを調べるコマンドが知りたい
（三行目）文章が書かれている行数だけを調べるコマンドが知りたい
（四行目）改行
（五行目）文章が書かれている行数だけを調べるコマンドが知りたい

この場合、文章が書かれている行は全て四行となります。これをコマンドで表示するコマンドが知りたいです。

調べてみるとwcコマンドの情報、行数や単語数を調べるコマンドがあるのですが文章が書かれている行数だけを調べるコマンド、もしくはオプションコマンドがあれば教えていただけると嬉しいです！

Comment: `grep -c '.' text_file`

Comment: 空白文字だけの行も考慮すると、こちらが参考になるかも。[count (non-blank) lines-of-code in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114814/9014308) さらに全角空白はどうか分かりませんが。